# Bootstrap dropdown link follows link instantly on mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to create a dropdown menu in a navbar where the toggle should be a link.

The problem is if i remove the data-toggle tag it's working perfekt on iOS. On the first click it opens the dropdown and on the second it follows the link.
But with the same situation on Android it's following the link instantly so you can't open the dropdown.

But if i add the data-toggle tag the link button isn't clickable anymore.

```
<li class="normal nav-item dropdown">
  <a href="/online-showroom" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Online Showroom</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="/online-showroom/19-jahrhundert" class="normal dropdown-item">19. Jahrhundert</a>
    <a href="/online-showroom/impressionisten" class="normal dropdown-item">Impressionisten</a>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Has someone a solution or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance